# Windows Explorer Not Showing Folders / Files Created in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

So, I made a small WPF app that allows you to template folder/file structures and save/load them.

When the app is initially installed, it has a Template folder in the root installation folder. I started out saving and loading templates to it (using SaveFileDialog and OpenFileDialog, then writing/parsing to/from xml). This worked fine.

I then wanted to test out what directory would first be opened through those buttons if I were to delete that folder (since even on a fresh install it went to the last opened directory, which I wanted to sort out). However, after deleting the folder, it still appeared in the file dialogs. I could create new folders within the file dialogs, and even still parse the xml files that aren't there anymore. So now, within the application I can see a Templates folder, load an XML from scratch and save XML files to it, and the app works perfectly. If I go to that directory in Windows Explorer, the Templates directory isn't there, nor are any of the files that I'm able to open (I've also tried using the search box and F5, doesn't show).

Any idea what could be causing this bug?

Here is the basic code I'm doing to save/load these files:

```
private void LoadTemplate ( object sender , RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog ();

        dialog.Filter = "xml files |*.xml";
        dialog.FilterIndex = 2;

        if ( dialog.ShowDialog () == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK )
        {
            string path = dialog.FileName;

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
            doc.Load ( path );

            if ( doc.DocumentElement != null )
            {
                XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes ( "Folders" ) [ 0 ].ChildNodes;
                List < Folder > _folders = new List < Folder > ();
                int currentLevel = 0;

                foreach ( XmlNode node in nodes )
                {
                    addItemToList ( ref _folders , node , currentLevel );
                }

                folders = _folders;
                DeployHierarchy.ItemsSource = folders;
                DeployHierarchy.Items.Refresh ();
            }
        }
    }

private void SaveTemplate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog savefile1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        savefile1.Filter = "xml files |*.xml";
        savefile1.FilterIndex = 2;

        if (savefile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
            XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement ( "Root" );
            XmlElement currentEl = ( XmlElement ) root.AppendChild ( doc.CreateElement ( "Folders" ) );
            doc.AppendChild ( root );

            for (int i = 0; i < folders.Count; i++)
            {
                addElement( ref doc , ref currentEl, ref i, ref currentEl);
            }

            doc.Save ( savefile1.FileName );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have created the folders/files in a security-restricted folder and are not running your WPF app as Administrator, in which case the physical files are located in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`.